# Slicer on Power Bi Gantt Chart 2.2.3

Tags: powerbi-desktop, timeline, gantt-chart, powerbi-custom-visuals

I am building a production dashboard in Power bi using Gantt Chart (by Microsoft Corporation).

In this dashboard, I am not able to filter the timeline based on dates showing only on weekdays and also user wants to view the timeline in hours based on working hours from 8 am to 5 pm.

Can someone help me with the filter on the Gantt Chart?

I tried to use the Dax query Measure = var _start_date = MAX('Date'[Date])
  `var _cur_task_start =MAX('Table'[StartDate])    var _cur_task_end = MAX('Table'[EndDate])    var _days =VALUE(FORMAT( _cur_task_end - _cur_task_start , "0"))    var _cur_year =DATE(YEAR( MAX('Date'[Date])),12,31)    var _cur_year_1 = DATE(YEAR( MAX('Date'[Date])),1,1)    var _days2 = IF(_cur_task_end> _cur_year ,VALUE(FORMAT( _cur_year-_cur_task_start, "0")),_days)    var _end2 = IF(_cur_year<_cur_task_end,_cur_year,_cur_task_end)    var _days3 = VALUE(FORMAT( _end2-_cur_year_1, "0"))    return    IF( _cur_task_start <_cur_year_1 && _cur_task_end >=_cur_year_1 && _start_date=_cur_year_1 ,   _days3,IF(_start_date=_cur_task_start,_days2,BLANK()))`

which was provided in the forum https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Desktop/Date-slicer-in-Gantt-charts/m-p/3240761 but did not work as this can only filter on Year and not other day or month. With a Similar process how to create a Dax query to Fitler on weekends and working time?